# Flatten Ragged LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap where CommonEnum represents a type of byte[] that I want to keep track of.

```
LinkedHashMap<CommonEnum, byte[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<CommonEnum, byte[]>();
```

What is the most efficient way in Java to flatten this into a continuous

`byte[]`

with the same ordering (thats why the HashMap is Linked).

Comment: Why do you have a `Byte[]` instead of `byte[]`?

Comment: Ah.. I didnt think you could use byte[] with generics..My mistake

Comment: You can't use primitive types as type arguments, but array types are reference types in Java (even arrays of primitives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use a `LinkedHashMap<CommonEnum, byte[]>`, it gets easier, and I have no idea why you would use `Byte[]`, so I assume this.

I'm not sure about *most efficient*, but these two would be what I think about:

- 1. create a byte[] large enough (either estimate it or calculate by adding the sizes)
  2. loop through the values, using `System.arraycopy` for each.
  3. If the array was to long, use `Arrays.copyOf` to shorten it.
- 1. Create a ByteArrayOutputStream
  2. loop through the values, write each byte[] to the stream.
  3. get the array.

By the way, if your CommonEnum values are always of the same order (and you can use this order as the order in the enum definition), you can use an `EnumMap` instead.

Comment: Definitely the way to do it (+1). I guess not everybody realizes that a byte[] is an Object, which might be an explanation ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of `ByteArrayOutputStream` -- you could iterate through the entries in the map, and for each `Byte[]` value, iterate through the members, `write()`ing them to the stream. Then call `toByteArray()` at the end to get the flat version.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of elements and the size, the fastest way might be to first calculate the total length, create a new byte array, and copy the values using `System.arraycopy`. However, using `ByteArrayOutputStream` is also good.